# Reading analog moisture signal from Arduino over USB to RPi3 and publishing via paho MQTT

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

This program is meant to read a moisture sensor attached to an Arduino UNO board via USB to a Raspberry Pi3 which broadcasts it over MQTT.

I am looking for any constructive criticism.

```
import serial
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


def main():
    try:
        while 1:
            sendMQTT(read_sensor("clean"),"Planty/moisture_readings")
            alerts()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "\n\nExiting via Keyboard Interrupt"


def debugger():
    # This is just to test each reading
    moisture_clean = read_sensor("clean")
    output = "Soil Moisture is " + str(moisture_clean) + "%"
    moisture_raw_adjusted = read_sensor("raw_adjusted")
    output += "\nRaw_adjusted is " + str(moisture_raw_adjusted)
    moisture_raw = read_sensor("raw")
    output += "\nRaw is " + str(moisture_raw)
    sendMQTT(output, "Planty/debug")


def alerts():
    # Generates alerts that are humanly readable for certain moisture thresholds
    moisture = read_sensor("clean")
    alert_low = 10
    alert_high = 90
    alert_threshold = 30
    if moisture <= alert_low:
        output = "**Moisture is below 10%**"
    if moisture <= alert_threshold and moisture > alert_low:
        output = "***Moisture is between 10%` and 30%, watering***"
        relay(14)
        time.sleep(60*1)
    if moisture >= alert_high:
        output = "***Moisture is above 90%***"
    sendMQTT(output, "Planty/alerts")


def read_sensor(choice):
    # Read analog moisture data from moisture probe via Arduino UNO plugged into
    # the RPi via USB
    min = 330
    max = 970
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
    #Line below handles the problem of the Arduino returning more than 1 reading
    raw_data = int(str.split(ser.readline())[0])
    if choice == "raw":
        moisture = raw_data
    #Stop readings going over or under 0 or 100%
    if raw_data < min:
        raw_data = min
    if raw_data > max:
        raw_data = max
    if choice == "raw_adjusted":
        moisture = raw_data
    if choice == "clean":
        #Get moisture as  % reading
        moisture = int(round(100-(100/float(max-min))*(raw_data-min), 0))
    return moisture


def relay(pin):
    # Turn on relay via PIN.HIGH
    try:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setup(pin,GPIO.OUT,initial=1)
        sendMQTT("Turning Relay1 ON", "Planty/relay")
        GPIO.output(pin,0)
        time.sleep(5)
        sendMQTT("Turning Relay1 OFF", "Planty/relay")
        GPIO.output(pin,1)
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()


def sendMQTT(output, topic):
    # Publish to MQTT for given topic
    host = "MQTTBroker.local"
    user = "user"
    password = "password"
    mqttc = mqtt.Client()
    mqttc.username_pw_set(user, password)
    mqttc.connect(host, 1883)
    mqttc.publish(topic, output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here're some changes that I'd personally do:

#### [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Guidlines

1. Be consistent when writing code! You used both *camelCase* and *snake_case* conventions when you declared your functions. Chose one of them and keep it that way. PEP8 recommends the second one.
2. Talking about consistency, you should also have a space after each `#`. More, when you want to write what your function is doing, you should use the following:

```
def read_sensor(choice):
    """
    Read analog moisture data from moisture probe via Arduino UNO plugged into
    the RPi via USB
    """
    # ...
```

3. After each comma (or any other operator) you should have a <kbd>space</kbd>
4. This: `if moisture <= alert_threshold and moisture > alert_low:` can be simplified using a chained expression:

```
if alert_low < moisture <= alert_threshold:
    ....
```

5. Use string `format()` instead of using the old `+` operator.
6. Constants should be *UPPER_CASED* (but not inside functions). I just took them out.

#### Personal anecdote:

- It feels a bit weird to have the `main()` function at the beginning and everything within that function after. I'd just move it to the end as it will look more naturally.
- You have several [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) which should be declared at the beginning. Doing this, you'll be able to modify their value faster than going through all the code and trying to remember what does what.
- Don't store variables if you use them only once. It will make you're code harder to follow and it will speed it down (*don't think of it as a big speed down but even so...*)

The above will lead our code to the following:

```
import serial
import time
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

ALERT_LOW = 10
ALERT_HIGH = 90
ALERT_TRESHOLD = 30
RELAY_TIME = 14
TIME_TO_SLEEP = 60 * 1
MIN = 330
MAX = 970
RATE = 9600


def read_sensor(choice):
    """
    Read analog moisture data from moisture probe via Arduino UNO plugged into
    the RPi via USB
    """
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', RATE)

    # Line below handles the problem of the Arduino returning more than 1 reading
    raw_data = int(str.split(ser.readline())[0])
    if choice == "raw":
        moisture = raw_data

    # Stop readings going over or under 0 or 100%
    if raw_data < MIN:
        raw_data = MIN
    if raw_data > MAX:
        raw_data = MAX
    if choice is "raw_adjusted":
        moisture = raw_data
    if choice == "clean":
        # Get moisture as  % reading
        moisture = int(round(100 - (100 / float(MAX - MIN)) * (raw_data - MIN), 0))

    return moisture


def send_mqtt(output, topic):
    """Publish to MQTT for given topic"""
    host, user, password, port = "MQTTBroker.local", "user", "password", 1883

    mqttc = mqtt.Client()
    mqttc.username_pw_set(user, password)
    mqttc.connect(host, port)
    mqttc.publish(topic, output)


def alerts():
    """ Generates alerts that are humanly readable for certain moisture thresholds"""
    moisture, output = read_sensor("clean"), ''

    if moisture <= ALERT_LOW:
        output = "**Moisture is below 10%**"
    if ALERT_LOW < moisture <= ALERT_TRESHOLD:
        output = "***Moisture is between 10%` and 30%, watering***"
        relay(RELAY_TIME)
        time.sleep(TIME_TO_SLEEP)
    if moisture >= ALERT_HIGH:
        output = "***Moisture is above 90%***"
    send_mqtt(output, "Planty/alerts")
    
    
def debugger():
    """This is just to test each reading"""
    output = "Soil Moisture is: {}%\n" \
             "Raw_adjusted is: {}\n" \
             "Raw is: {}".format(read_sensor("clean"), read_sensor("raw_adjusted"), read_sensor("raw"))

    send_mqtt(output, "Planty/debug")


def relay(pin):
    """Turn on relay via PIN.HIGH"""
    try:
        gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
        gpio.setwarnings(False)
        gpio.setup(pin, gpio.OUT, initial=1)
        send_mqtt("Turning Relay1 ON", "Planty/relay")
        gpio.output(pin, 0)
        time.sleep(5)
        send_mqtt("Turning Relay1 OFF", "Planty/relay")
        gpio.output(pin, 1)
    finally:
        gpio.cleanup()


def main():
    try:
        while 1:
            send_mqtt(read_sensor("clean"), "Planty/moisture_readings")
            alerts()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n\nExiting via Keyboard Interrupt")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Since you're using the try/except in main only for `KeyboardInterrupt` I'd completely remove it as it seems redundant.

```
def main():
    while 1:
        send_mqtt(read_sensor("clean"), "Planty/moisture_readings")
        alerts()
```

Comment: Thanks @dex'ter. I changed the camelCase to snake locally after the upload as well as the docstring you pointed out. Along with the spaces after the `#`'s.
I should have caught that before uploading it.

I will implement the other changes you have mentioned so far, thank you!

Comment: I also switched out `sendMQTT()` to `pub_MQTT()` as you publish to an MQTT broker.
`mqttc` in `sendMQTT()` was also changed to `mqtt_client`

The I changed the magic numbers to include `HOST`, `PASSWORD`, `USER`. Further `RELAY_TIME` in your example should actually be `RELAY_PIN` - as it is a GPIO pin not a timer.

Comment: It is not the first time that I read from you that comparing strings is done with `is`. Can you back up the claim? Because `a = 'a b'; a is 'a b'` returns `False` (even though `a = 'ab'; a is 'ab'` returns `True`).

Comment: @MathiasEttinger thanks for spotting that. My mistake. I edited the answer accordingly